# Join three selects into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 13.0.5102.14.

I have these three selects:

```
declare @prodID int = 1;
declare @lotAI varchar(4) = '10';

select cod.Serial as ItemNO,
       varData.Value as Lot,
       pro.ProductCode as Product
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.VariableData varData,
       dbo.Product pro,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 1 and
       varData.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       varData.VariableDataId = @lotAI and
       proOrd.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       pro.ProductId = proOrd.ProductId

select cod.Serial as Box
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.AggregationChildren aggCh,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 2 and
       cod.CodeId = aggCh.AggregationChildrenId

select cod.Serial as Pallet
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.Aggregation agg,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 3 and
       cod.CodeId = agg.AggregationId
```

I want to join these three selects into one to get this:

```
cod.Serial as ItemNO,
cod.Serial as Box,
varData.Value as Lot,
cod.Serial as Pallet,
pro.ProductCode as Product
```

My problem here is that I'm using `Code` table to get three different values.

How can I do it to join these three selects into one?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to use proper, explicit, standard, readable JOIN syntax.

Comment: Proper explicit joins have been around since 1992; so it is definitely time you learned them. No documentation even references the old 1989 syntax. Have a look at [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: As for how to to join these queries, some sample data and expected results would be nice here. I doubt you need 3 queries either, considering that every "starts" at `dbo.Code`, but without expected behaviour this is impossible to answer without a lot of guess work.

Comment: is it also intentional that you have a `CROSS JOIN` to tables like `dbo.ProductionOrder `?

Comment: What are the joining columns for table dbo.Code ?

Comment: @Larnu I have put three queries to show you what I want.

Comment: @SureshGajera The joining columns are on the `where` clauses.

Comment: @larnu Yes, I have to retrieve a value from `dbo.ProductionOrder`. Thanks.

Comment: *"**a** value"* , not **every**. A `CROSS JOIN` returns *every* row from the other table.

Comment: I ask a question, and someone thinks that I have to know what I'm asking. If I know what I'm asking, I wouldn't ask. Please, stop downvoting. I'm learning.

Comment: Well, you got three answers and didn't commented or picked any of them as answer. Any of them offered you any kind of help? Also I do think your question is not very clear and has been asked before, but I do not think it should've been downvoted, especially without any kind of explanation or advise. I think if anything it should've been closed for duplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty using union and assuming your current queries work.

```
select cod.Serial,' as ItemNO'
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.VariableData varData,
       dbo.Product pro,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 1 and
       varData.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       varData.VariableDataId = @lotAI and
       proOrd.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       pro.ProductId = proOrd.ProductId
union
select cod.Serial,' as Box'
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.AggregationChildren aggCh,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 2 and
       cod.CodeId = aggCh.AggregationChildrenId
union      
Select varData.Value,' as Lot'
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.VariableData varData,
       dbo.Product pro,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 1 and
       varData.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       varData.VariableDataId = @lotAI and
       proOrd.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       pro.ProductId = proOrd.ProductId
union
select cod.Serial,' as Pallet'
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.Aggregation agg,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 3 and
       cod.CodeId = agg.AggregationId
union      
select pro.ProductCode,' as Product'
  from dbo.Code cod,
       dbo.VariableData varData,
       dbo.Product pro,
       dbo.ProductionOrder proOrd
 where cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       cod.AggregationLevel = 1 and
       varData.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       varData.VariableDataId = @lotAI and
       proOrd.ProductionOrderId = @prodID and
       pro.ProductId = proOrd.ProductId
```

You could improve this question by providing sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it there's two solutions for your problem, although the code you provided doesn't help much.

**Using JOINS**

This is by far preferable solution, as you avoid getting the same value over and over from the same database (which is what you're currently doing).

Try to build from something like:

```
SELECT 
   cod.Serial, varData.Value
FROM
   Code cod
JOIN
   VariableData varData
ON
   cod.ProductionOrderId = varData.ProductionOrderId
WHERE
   cod.ProductionOrderId = @prodID
```

**Using UNION**

You can always bundle together queries results using the union operator, which combines the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

Syntax would be like:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check your result set as you are creating different data sets with your joins, but Case when cod.AggregationLevel = 1 then cod.Serial end as Itemno
and Case when cod.AggregationLevel = 2 then cod.Serial end as Box
and Case when cod.AggregationLevel = 3 then cod.Serial end as Pallet should work as AggregationLevel is in the dob.code table. This gives you a NULL value but you could fix that by adding an else to the case statement.